# onbackpress webview shows page not available in samsung s4 device only

Tags: webview

Posturl with header to the webview it load the webpage first time then click in to the next page in webview then go back it shows me Page not available in only samsung s4 device.

Comment: I suggest a re-write for the question. Removed the fluff because that had no value.

Comment: you have any ans about this issue @JamesZ